# Do very large fields have a negative effect on MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, database, django

I'm currently building a website with Django and want to host user bio style pages which may be up to a several KB. These fields don't necessarily need to be searched but do need to be served when the username is looked up.

Will it have a negative effect to store this data in the db? Would my server run better if I were to use static text files with a link in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is "storing your data in MySql" (vs an external text file): storing the data in the database is definitely the best approach here.

"BLOB" can be a generic term - in which case Oleksi is absolutely correct (I marked him +1, not down!).

But the specific MySql type you want is indeed TEXT:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Storing as TEXT in your mySql database will have many benefits (including, but not limited to, "performance").

There's no advantage to storing the text in external files that I can think of.

PS:

I have a legacy PHP/MySQL web app that uses a very old version that predates free-text searching in MySQL.  If I can't port it to a new server, I'm seriously considering saving all the "notes" data in external files, just so I can run a indexer like "Lucene" against the text.  But that's the exception to the rule.  Storing in the database is almost certainly the best choice in your case.  IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

You can store them in the DB and they probably won't be the bottleneck in your performance. Make sure that the column type is set to [TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) and MySQL will treat that data as intelligently as possible to avoid performance problems.

Comment: What's your reason for storing as BLOB instead of TEXT? Isn't BLOB usually reserved for binary data?

Comment: @Ilion yes, TEXT is more appropriate. Edited.

Comment: @SiGanteng the link for TEXT and BLOB is the same. The link I posted contains information on both.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry just saw the url and it says `blob.html`, so I assumed it was a mistake :s

Comment: @SiGanteng No problem. Easy to make mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed by @Oleksi and @paulsm4, storing the data in the database can be beneficial, for all the reasons they discuss. They didn't however mention the reasons why you might not want to:

1. Should a BLOB or TEXT column end up in a temporary table during query optimisation, this table will end up on-disk, even if it is small enough it would have otherwise been in memory. You should therefore try to avoid selecting a BLOB or TEXT column unless you know you need it; should definitely avoid `select *` (which is good practice anyway).
2. A BLOB/TEXT column is stored inside the database. Assuming it is relatively static content, you can gain performance/scalability/cost advantages by serving them as static files behind a dedicated low-overhead httpd service/cache.
3. Where a BLOB represents media, it is almost always better to store it externally behind a dedicated streaming service.
4. Where the content is changed, it is easier to incorporate version control when the data is stored externally than in the database.
5. A BLOB/TEXT column is going to be stored on the same server as the rest of the table. BLOB/TEXT access generally has very different read patterns to table/index access. This means that access to the BLOB/TEXT will pollute your buffer-cache, affecting your database performance; and, table/index access will interfere with sequential read scheduling, affecting BLOB/TEXT performance.

Now of course 2 and 5 only apply if you are hitting the performance limit of your database server; 3 and 4 are rather special cases; and, 1 can normally be resolved by splitting the table, or rewriting the relevant queries. So most of the time these don't apply, and from the question it sounds like they don't apply in your case either; however, the generally correct advice "use a BLOB/TEXT" does have its exceptions, and it is well worth understanding what they are.